# Processing components selectively with "process" along with setting partialSubmit to true

Tags: jsf, primefaces

```
<h:form id="form">            
    <p:panel id="panel">
        <p:messages autoUpdate="true"/>

        <p:inputText value="#{bean.value1}" required="true"/><br/>
        <p:inputText value="#{bean.value2}" required="true"/><br/>

        <p:commandButton partialSubmit="true"
                         process="panel"
                         update="@none"
                         actionListener="#{bean.action}"
                         value="Submit"/>
    </p:panel>

    <p:panel id="panel1"></p:panel>
    <p:panel id="panel2"></p:panel>
    <p:panel id="panel3"></p:panel>

    <!-- Other components -->
</h:form>
```

In such examples, although components to be processed are listed explicitly with `process`, is it always worth setting `partialSubmit` to `true`? Does it have a little or more performance impact?

This should not be needed as a view is automatically processed partially, when components to be processed are listed explicitly with `process`.

In both the cases, the log message received will be identical something like the following.

```
10/24/2015, 9:38:20 AM : Initiating ajax request.
10/24/2015, 9:38:20 AM : Form to post form.
10/24/2015, 9:38:20 AM : URL to post /Project/location/Test.
10/24/2015, 9:38:20 AM : Post Data:javax.faces.partial.ajax=true&javax.faces.source=form%3Aj_idt11&javax.faces.partial.execute=form%3Apanel&javax.faces.partial.render=%40none&form%3Aj_idt11=form%3Aj_idt11&form%3Aj_idt8=qqq&form%3Aj_idt10=qqq&javax.faces.ViewState=-8717858113332784641%3A8629301927694502525
10/24/2015, 9:38:20 AM : Response received succesfully.
10/24/2015, 9:38:20 AM : DOM is updated.
10/24/2015, 9:38:20 AM : Response completed.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the example you posted it indeed does not make a difference. All inputs you have are inside the panel that you 'process'. If you put one of the inputs outside the panel, you'll see that the value of that input is not submitted.

For small forms there is no real advantage, but for larger forms that contain many ajax calls it does make a difference. Check the [PrimeFaces showcase for a 'good' example](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/partialSubmit.xhtml)

Comment: They used `process="name"` in both the cases in the showcase example. In that case, `partialSubmit` should not have any effect whether it is set to `true` or `false` i.e. it should not process the whole form, since `process` is set to a particular one component only in both the cases. It however, generates a very long query-string, when `partialSubmit` is set to `false`.

Comment: I rest my case.... The difference is in the submitting, not the processing. process (server side) != submitting (sending data from client to server)...  And as you write in your comment, you see exactly that difference. A long query string vs a short one.

Comment: Thank you. I am making extensive usage of `partialSubmit` and `partialSubmitFilter`. Such as events inside a `<p:dataTable>` like `rowEditCancel`, `page`, `sort` - `<p:ajax event="page" partialSubmit="true" partialSubmitFilter=":not(:input)" process="@this" .../>` which reduces network traffic.